# How can I using pattern matching on field aready in an awk statement?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I'm actually trying to us a linux ps to get PID, etc from a java command.  As I might have more that one, I would like to break out the last field and extract the unique path.

For example, my current command is:

```
ps -ef |grep java |grep root|awk {'print $1"\t"$5"\t"$2"\t"$13}'
```

My results are something like:

```
root 08:11  1234  -Djava.library.path=/opt/path/to/My_Application/libs
root 08:11  1234  -Djava.library.path=/opt/path/to/My_Other_Application/libs
```

I want to make my output look like:

```
root 08:11  1234  My_Application
root 08:11  1234  My_Other_Application
```

I thought I had it figured out, but not quite...The closest I came was to try:

```
ps -ef |grep java |grep root|awk {'print $1"\t"$5"\t"$2"\t"substr($13,33,34)}'
```

which gets me to:

```
root 08:11  1234  My_Application/libs
root 08:11  1234  My_Other_Application/libs
```

Thinking I can just drop off the last 5 characters of the fourth field, I've tried:

```
ps -ef |grep java |grep root|awk {'print $1"\t"$5"\t"$2"\t"substr($13,33,34)}'|awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"substr($4,1,(length($4)-5))}'
```

But this does not drop the last 5 characters as I would expect...it seems to do something like:

```
root 08:11  1234  My_Applic
root 08:11  1234  My_Other_Application
```

UPDATE:  Initial results from ps -ef statment (shoudl be universal):

ps -ef
UID  PID   PPID  C STIME TTY       TIME    CMD
---- ----  ----  - ----- ---   --------  --------------------------------------------------
root 1234   100  0 2013  ?     00:00:02  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0.0/jre/binjava -cp /opt/path/to/My_Application/jars/*:/opt/path/to/My_Application/properties/:/opt/path/to/My_Application/*: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/path/to/My_Application/properties/logging.props -DkeyFile=/opt/path_to/My_Application/properties/key.file -Djava.library.path=/opt/path/to/My_application/libs
 ...etc (several more options passed...but not needed)

Comment: First off, you should use arguments to `ps` to limit its output fields to the ones you want and the order you want them in. Second, you can use the awk `split` function to re-split a field on a new delimiter to split your path/etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, would also use `ps -u root`, but then there is no `root ...` in output of `ps`

Comment: That's not the option I was talking about (but that's not a bad start) and if you know the username you can add it back in your awk later. I was talking about the column selection options. You can control what bits of information ps spits out at you instead of having to parse out the columns you want from the default output.

Comment: @EtanReisner yeah of course....

Comment: I did try "split" on the last one, but I kept getting two characters..I used it instead of the last substring...Let me look in my history, and perhaps you can tell me what's wrong with it:  Okay, looks like I had tried: split($4,x,"/") instead of the substr($4,1,(length($4)-5, but all I got for the fourth field was the number 2 (presumably, two "array values?"...But how do I disply the first array value instead of my current 4th field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for a way to extract the application name, you need to use `gsub` twice in awk. Check this example:

```
echo "-Djava.library.path=/opt/path/to/My_Application/libs" | \
awk '{ gsub(/\/[^\/]*$/, "", $4); gsub(/.*\//, "", $4); print $4}'
```

Output:

```
My_Application
```

This should work with every version of `awk`.

---

The final command can be optimized, as you don't need the `grep` commands, you can filter the lines of interest in `awk` directly:

```
ps -ef | awk '/^root.*\-Djava/ { gsub(/\/[^\/]*$/, "", $8); gsub(/.*\//, "", $8); print $8}'
```

Comment: hek2mgl - From an echo statement I'd just a field separator "/" and print the 5th field.  What I need to do is extrat that value "My_Application" from a previous awk output.  THanks.

Comment: Yes...It returns zero.

Comment: Oh, when piping from `ps -ef` it is `$8`, not `$4`, sorry my fault. Can you try it again?

Comment: `awk`s `split()` function might also be of interest here as an alternative to overly-complex `gsub()` patterns.

Comment: @twalberg .. Yeah, after debate with EdMorton, I like his attempt (using `NF-1` instead of `$8`) most.

Comment: hek2mgl - Just tried it again...Okay, while I don't understand it, It does now print out what I want.  So my final command is:  ps -ef | awk '/^root.*\-Djava/ { gsub(/\/[^\/]*$/, "", $13); gsub(/.*\//, "", $13); print $1"\t"$5"\t"$2,"\t"$13}'

Comment: While I was hoping to get Ed Morton's response to work, this solution does exactly what I've asked.  I've just tested against eight different processes on four different servers!  Works great!  Therefore I'll mark this answered! Thanks for the assist!  KSL.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef |awk -F' +|/' '/root.*java/{print $1, $2, $3, $8}'
```

Comment: This will work as long as the path has the same structure and length as in question, using `gsub` to retain the second last argument of path is more generic

Comment: @hek2mgl if using the 2nd-last field is more robust than using the 8th, you'd just use $(NF-1) instead of $8. I don't think using gsub() would do anything more useful.

Comment: Use `NF-1` and you'll recieve an upvote. Then it is much better then `gsub`, I didn't had this in mind

Comment: However, I'll upvote this, at the end it looks as powerful as gsub here but much less complex.. +1

Comment: I just don't know if $(NF-1) is any better or worse than $8. If the input doesn't match what was posted, then who knows what it really looks like (e.g. maybe there's an additional "/" at the end of some lines)? If this doesn't work for the OP then he can tell us why and post some more truly representative sample input and then I'll see about changing it.

Comment: Im not able to get this command to give the correct result.  $1 is the entire ps statement up to the application name, $2 is the command (minus the initial "/" for the /usr/lib/jvm/java statement.  $3 is the remainder of the ps statement.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought the initial text you showed was your command input but on re-reading I see it's actually the output. Update your question to show the output of your `ps -ef` (i.e. the input to the awk command I'm suggesting you use) so we can help you identify which fields to select for printing. Also tell us which, if any, white space in that `ps -ef` output is tabs as opposed to blank chars.

Comment: @EdMorton (response to your second last comment) -> Yes, you are right :)